# Вопросы после двоеточия

Tags: пунктуация, двоеточие

Недавно столкнулась с таким предложением:

"В его голове крутились вопросы по типу: кого это могло принести или опять работать?".

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в данном случае правильно расставить знаки препинания. В целом я знаю правило, но основная проблема в этом "или". Так и хочется написать так:

"В его голове крутились вопросы по типу: "кого это могло принести?" или "опять работать?".

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 3):

Можно записать так.

*В его голове крутились вопросы вроде таких: "**Кого это могло принести?" или "Опять работать**?"*

Подобное оформление можно посмотреть у Розенталя § 51. Прямая речь внутри слов автора, пункт 2 http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=159

*Не говорить же: **«Эй, собака!» или «Эй, кошка!»*** — две реплики, разделенные неповторяющимся союзом ИЛИ.

**Строчные** буквы допускаются, например: Это «не хочу» поразило Антона Прокофьевича (Г.). Но здесь лучше подойдут **прописные** буквы.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138801/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon---).

Comment: Придумал пример, который схож с этим: *Он подумал о фруктах вроде таких: банан или яблоко.* ИЛИ подходит? Нет!

Comment: ОК, до вечера...

Comment: Вечер с 18:00 начинается, кстати. Ещё 5 минут.

Comment: Уже вечер, друзья, уже вечер…И какие у вас опять проблемы, почему "нет!"? «Он подумал о фруктах вроде яблока или банана».  То есть его  устроит любой вариант, допускаются оба. Почему? Да все потому же. «Языковые примеры дают возможность  ОБЕИХ ИНТЕРПРЕТАЦИЙ для союза ИЛИ: (1) Выбор одной из двух ситуаций; (2) возможность обеих ситуаций».  Ваше предложение ничем не отличается от того, что было в вопросе – ничего не изменилось.

Comment: Но вы, я знаю, любите примеры: Целый день идет дождь или снег. – А вам что больше нравится, дождь или снег? Здесь ясно видно, что союз ИЛИ имеет два значения, которые определяются по контексту.

Comment: Вы забываете о том, что там говорится и о случаях, когда возможен лишь один вариант. А в другом случае тоже выбор, но ситуация с обоими вариантами допустима. Такое происходит, когда есть условие, как в их примере. Не сказал бы, что в этом примере допускаются оба, но там явно проще это допустить. Мой пример же имеет другую структуру — такую, как у вас в ответе: *Он подумал о фруктах вроде таких: банан или яблоко.* Здесь ИЛИ не подходит.

Comment: Смотрите, что получается. Если первостепенная задача — объединить варианты и, например, показать, что думал и о том и о том, а не лишь об одном, то ставится союз И либо запятая, если же один вариант допустим, то ставится ИЛИ. Всё просто. В моём примере исключается то, что думал лишь об одном типе. Поэтому ИЛИ не подходит.

Comment: Так что дело даже не в том, допустимы два варианта сразу или нет. Дело в том, что у нас не допускается ситуация, когда один вариант. А ИЛИ её допускает.

Comment: oleedd,  у вас какая-то странная логика, которую мало кто понимает.  Бесполезно обсуждать, мы друг друга не слышим. Может, вы говорите что-то интересное и правильное , но на непонятном языке.  Поэтому дискуссия закончена. Приятного вам вечера...

Comment: Ладно, придётся всё упростить. Для того, чтобы два варианта были допустимы, нужно условие (так мне кажется). Можем просто упростить мой пример: *Он думал о банане или яблоке.* Разве допускается, что он думал об обоих фруктах? Но важнее то, что сказано выше: у нас ситуация, когда он думал и о банане, и о яблоке (он не думал о чём-то одном, это исключается). Поэтому ИЛИ нельзя. Верно?

Comment: Я  уже хочу спать... и больше ничего не знаю. Но догадываюсь, что значение  ИЛИ определяется исключительно по тексту, иначе его вычислить невозможно. Но вы все равно стараетесь это сделать.

Comment: Продолжим завтра? Не увиливайте опять.

Comment: А потом послезавтра...

Comment: Нет, мы почти уже на финише, послезавтра не понадобится. И вы перекрутили, там так: Языковые примеры дают возможность ОБЕИХ ИНТЕРПРЕТАЦИЙ для союза ИЛИ: (1) Выбор одной из двух ситуаций; (2) возможность как одной ситуации, так и обеих сразу. (2) далеко не всегда. Мы не это обсуждаем, а конкретные примеры, это просто к слову.

Comment: Завтра суббота, выходной день., работать нельзя. К тому же  последние жаркие денечки...

Comment: Тут дело пяти минут. Или давайте сейчас, или напишите, когда будете готовы.

Comment: А мне кажется, что это дело пяти дней, пяти часов и пяти минут.  Надо подумать...

Comment: А сделаю так, что всё будет быстро и безболезненно.

Comment: А зачем вам именно я? На форме много других участников, надо бы всех допросить.

Comment: Свидетели-то тем более есть! Sraron, про трансмиссию, эт самое, напишу как-нить...

Comment: Потому что вы ответили и не исправили. И не совсем правильно применяете то, что прочитали о ИЛИ.

Comment: Да, Александр, вы уж напишите как-нить...  А  то примкнули к большинству, а мы вас за своего считали.  А меня там еще и минусовали.  Свой голос мне уже после автор вопроса прислал.

Comment: Давайте закончим: 1) *Он думал о банане или яблоке.* Разве допускается, что он думал об обоих фруктах? 2) Если он думал об обоих фруктах (другого варианта быть не может), то ИЛИ нельзя. Верно?